# File uploaded via FTP has no content, and is checked out by an empty string?

Tags: ftp, locking

I've attempted to upload the same PHP file to my shared hosting server through Dreamweaver and Filezilla and in both cases my 2KB file gets uploaded onto the server as 0KB.

In Filezilla, I've attempted to upload in both ASCII and Binary mode and get the same result.

I renamed the local file, uploaded it, and it also ended up empty.

I created a new HTML file, 1KB, and uploaded it. It seemed to keep its size until I viewed the file on the server in which it showed up empty. I checked the server again, and the file was down to 0 bytes.

One strange thing I've noticed is that Dreamweaver marks the most recently uploaded file as "Checked out by: " - essentially nobody. All of the other files including files that have been emptied are "Checked out by: *my name*".

I'm at a loss.

Comment: Maybe the server is out of diskspace?

Comment: Good sir, that was exactly the problem. Apparently someone just uploaded 2GB of pictures and neglected to notify me. You're a saint. If you want to move your comment to an answer, I'll accept/upvote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd double check to see if the FTP server is out of disk space.